# how should 断面神 be interpreted?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

I'm stuck trying to guess what 断面神 might be.

**Context:** Expressing astonishment it's possible to find a place in Tokyo where croissant is about as good as in Paris (while looking at a photograph of said croissant, cut in half and showing the inside). The whole dialog:

> 「クロワッサン！」
>   「断面神！！」
>   「食べたすぎる！！！」

Comment: Perhaps 'godly cross-section' → 'incredible all the way through / in all respects'?

Comment: Replaced "teen-slang" tag because the use is not limited/labeled as kid's language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty much what has been mentioned in the answers and comments: godly cross-section or insides, parsed 断面{だんめん}・神{かみ}.  AS you know, croissants are intricately layered inside, so the comment is about how beautiful or awesome it is.

Note this is use of 神 is pretty much an internet-only thing, and is not used in everyday speech.

Comment: I hear kids and teenagers use 「神」 for this meaning in real life all the time.

Comment: I didn't include the photo, but it shows the inside of the croissant which is cut in half, so definitively this is the right interpretation. The girl saying that 
is in her twenties.

Comment: @l'électeur: Ahh, I guess I'm falling behind on the times.  I guess it makes sense, as kids and teens seem to use internet slang in real life.

Answer (score 5):

神 is sometimes used in the sense of "superb". For example, you can call a game you really like a 神ゲー. So maybe they are saying that the cross-section looks fantastic? Just a wild guess...

Comment: would tag it as the correct answer also, if I could.